# Ignoring X-Frame-Options in firefox webextension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to port my extension from Chrome to Firefox, however I have problem
with X-Frame-Options. My extension is pretty simple, all it does is create few
iframes, wait for them to load and then extract some data from the loaded pages.

This all works great it Chrome, however in Firefox I have problem that the page
does not load in the iframe (probably due to `X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM XXX`).

In Chrome having

```
"permissions": {
    "https://example.com/"
}
```

is enough to make browser ignore the X-Frame-Options, but in Firefox
it still does not work.

So, how can I force Firefox to ignore this X-Frame-Options for my extension (and
its pages)?

EDIT: I would just like to add that since I'm using injected content script anyway (to get data from the frame), I don't **need** it to be in an iframe. All I need is to render the page without it being visible to user (so new tabs etc. are no-go :/).

EDIT2: This 2 file extension works in chrome, but not in firefox:

`manifest.json`

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Iframe test",
  "description": "foobar",
  "version": "0.9.3",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "https://jisho.org/"
  ]
}
```

`popup.html`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="https://jisho.org"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it "just works" in Chrome because Chrome [doesn't support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options#Browser_compatibility) "ALLOW FROM".

Firefox does the right thing here, but you can intercept this header like any other with the [`webRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest) API, specifically [`webRequest.onHeadersReceived`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onHeadersReceived). Something like this (untested) should work:

```
browser.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener((details) => {
        let newHeaders = details.responseHeaders.filter(
            header => !header.name.toLowerCase().endsWith('frame-options')
        );
        return {responseHeaders: newHeaders};
    },
    {
        urls: [ 'https://jisho.org/*' ],
        types: [ 'sub_frame' ]
    },
    ['blocking', 'responseHeaders']
);
```

You also require the `webRequest` and `webRequestBlocking` permissions for this.

Comment: Yeeey this works, thank you so much :) I had no idea it works in chrome by accident.